# What is an efficient way to have an image change when on parent hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 12 buttons, all of which contain unique test, and a unique image. I want to implement the functionality in two ways:

1) on hover, the image changes to one that I have saved
2) on click, the image changes and is locked in to the one that I have saved.

I can do this in a long way where I have a function for each button, and thus 12 functions that change the div background color, the div text, and the image, but surely there must be an efficient way to do this with one single function for all buttons of a class?

EDIT SOME CODE:

HTML

```
      <div class="container" id="research-container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col s4"><a class="waves-effect waves-light btn research-categories" id="gas-mileage">Gas Mileage
            </a></div>
          <div class="col s4"><a class="waves-effect waves-light btn research-categories" id="safety">Safety</a></div>
          <div class="col s4"><a class="waves-effect waves-light btn research-categories">Acceleration</a></div>
          <div class="col s4"><a class="waves-effect waves-light btn research-categories">Handling</a></div>
          <div class="col s4"><a class="waves-effect waves-light btn research-categories" id="comfort">Comfort</a></div>
          <div class="col s4"><a class="waves-effect waves-light btn research-categories">High Tech
            <img class="button-pics" id="high-tech-button" src="../img/research-buttons/industrial-robot.png">
              </a></div>
          <div class="col s4"><a class="waves-effect waves-light btn research-categories">Leather Seats</a></div>
          <div class="col s4"><a class="waves-effect waves-light btn research-categories">Sound System</a></div>
          <div class="col s4"><a class="waves-effect waves-light btn research-categories">Don't Care</a></div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

JS:

this just changes the class to make the background/text color change

```
$(".research-categories").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("clicked");
});
```

and finally the css

```
.research-categories:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #007EE5;
}

.research-categories.clicked {
    background-color: #007EE5;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: Please post the relevant portions of your code, even if just the current HTML structure.

Comment: Just posted, thanks! Also to note, I have only added an image to one button, but each button will have its own custom image :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is the best way, however it works without writing a specific function for each and every image. You'd need to put two attributes on all of your images: `origImage` would be what your images "normal" state (this does not replace src), and `hoverImage` would be the hover image.

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/ee5w6mxz/2/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.research-categories').hover(
   function() { //Mouse Over
       var hoverImage = $(this).find('img').attr("hoverImage");
       $(this).find('img').attr("src", hoverImage);
   }, 
   function() { //Mouse Out
       var origImage = $(this).find('img').attr("origImage");
       $(this).find('img').attr("src", origImage);
   });

   $('.research-categories').click(function() { //Button click
      var hoverImage= $(this).find('img').attr("hoverImage");
      $(this).find('img').attr("src", hoverImage);
      $(this).off();
   });

});


<div class="container" id="research-container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col s4">
        <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn research-categories">High Tech
          <img class="button-pics" id="high-tech-button" src="../img/research-buttons/industrial-robot.png" origImage="../img/research-buttons/industrial-robot.png" hoverImage="../img/research-buttons/HOVER_IMAGE.jpg">
        </a>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry for the vague question. I thought I was clear that every button has unique content, meaning unique text, and a unique image. I made functions (which I updated in my post) that toggle the background/text to do exactly what I want, but now I just need to add the same to be done for each button's image (which is unique to that button)

Comment: thanks, I'll test it out! and aww at downvotes on the question I thought it was a pretty decent one to simplify the jquery :(

Comment: @VDog I think generally speaking, because your original post (prior to edit) did not have any code, or any HTML structure, it was seen as too broad. Without including what you've already done, it seems like you haven't even tried. StackOverflow is more to help with debugging, rather than "Hey can you guys do this for me?". Not saying you're guilty of this, but in the future be sure to provide anything you've attempted, or at least show that coming here to have someone assist was not your first choice.